# SDL window closes on startup and returns 0

Tags: c++, return, sdl, exit

The window closes as soon as i start the program. this is the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (!init())
    {
        printf("Could not initialize!");
    }
    else
    {
        bool quit = false;
        SDL_Event ev;

        while(!quit)
        {
            while(SDL_PollEvent(&ev))
            {
                if(ev.type = SDL_QUIT)
                {
                    quit = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    close();
    return 0;
}
```

Adding printf() statements narrowed it down to this section

```
while(SDL_PollEvent(&ev))
{
    if(ev.type = SDL_QUIT)
    {
        quit = true;
    }
}
```

If i change `while(SDL_PollEvent(&ev))` to `while(!SDL_PollEvent(&ev))` or `while(SDL_PollEvent(&ev) != 0)`
the window stays open but closes as soon as i mouse over it or try to move it.

[the SDL documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent)
says that `SDL_PollEvent` only returns 1 (true) if there is a pending event, and since the program returns 0 it seems like `SDL_PollEvent` must have returned 1 somehow and also that `ev.type` was set to `SDL_QUIT` without clicking the X button, which I find unlikely. So I probably did something wrong but I can't figure out what it is, and I have been trying to find a solution.

Also, here is the init() function.

```
bool init()
{
    bool success = true;
    if( SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        printf("SDL failed to initialize! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("Image Encrypter", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                  SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if(window == NULL)
        {
            printf("Window could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
            success = false;
        }
        else
        {
            screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
            if(screenSurface == NULL)
            {
                printf("Screen surface could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
            }
        }
    }
    return success;
}
```

The console does not output any of the printf statements in the init() function, so I don't think that's where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common error here:

```
if(ev.type = SDL_QUIT)
```

- this is an assignment, not a comparison. The first version of your code should work then.